# How to re-structure the git commits in github

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase

**Step 1:** I created a git repo on github, having License and Readme, initialized during creating of repo (master branch).

**Step 2:** On my PC, I did a git init in an already existing workspace having 2 Folders containing Arduino *.ino file. ( I didn't do a git clone here)

```
Workspace
|-Folder_1
|  |-Proj1.ino
|-Folder_2
|  |-Proj2.ino
|-.git
```

**Step 3:** From my PC I have pushed the development branch containing the local folders to the github.

Now I see a kind of detached development branch from master. I understood why so.

I would like to connect the master to development branch by bringing the 2 files "Readme.md and LICENCE" to the development branch. I donot want to bring these 2 projects from development to the master branch now. Is there a way possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it following these steps:

```
git checkout master 
git pull
git checkout development
git rebase master
git push --force
```

Then your development branch will have the master files and commit, and your branch will have one commit ahead of master, where you can merge with master by opening a merge request by example.